# AngularJS with ngMessages: skip pattern while length is invalid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-messages

I have such part of form:

```
<div ng-messages="submittedFrgPwd && forgotForm.username.$error" multiple>
  <div ng-message="pattern">{{ 'INVALID_EMAIL' | translate }}</div>
  <div ng-message="required">{{ 'EMPTY_EMAIL' | translate }}</div>
  <div ng-message="minlength">{{ 'SHORT_EMAIL' | translate }}</div>
  <div ng-message="maxlength">{{ 'LONG_EMAIL' | translate }}</div>
</div>
<input type="email" id="username-remember" name="username" ng-model="username" ng-minlength="8" ng-maxlength="200" required ng-pattern="email_regexp" ng-class="{ 'has-error': submittedFrgPwd && forgotForm.username.$invalid || submittedError}"/>
```

and for example:

when i enter email of normal length, but with invalid pattern i see only:

```
{{ 'INVALID_EMAIL' | translate }}
```

and this is normall.

but!

when i enter something like `a@a.a` i get both errors:

```
<div ng-message="pattern">{{ 'INVALID_EMAIL' | translate }}</div>
<div ng-message="minlength">{{ 'SHORT_EMAIL' | translate }}</div>
```

but is this real, to **skip pattern messages until my min length is valid**?

i try it so:
`data-ng-show="submittedFrgPwd && forgotForm.username.$error.pattern && !forgotForm.username.$error.minlength && !forgotForm.username.$error.maxlength"`

seems to work, but it's to ugly)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by specifieng `,` separated error, Its like `AND` operation which you are specifying `minlength && pattern` both error should occur.

**Markup**

```
<div ng-message="minlength,pattern">{{ 'INVALID_EMAIL' | translate }}</div>
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/epRHusrrLYHOsgfesjYg?p=preview)

**Update**

Seems like `ng-message="minlength,pattern"` is not working, I'd suggest you to use alternative solution by using `ng-if="!forgotForm.username.$error.minlength"`

```
<form name="forgotForm" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <label>
      Enter your name:
      <div ng-messages="submittedFrgPwd && forgotForm.username.$error" multiple>
        <div ng-message="required">{{ 'EMPTY_EMAIL' }}</div>
        <div ng-message="minlength">{{ 'SHORT_EMAIL' }}</div>
        <div ng-message="maxlength">{{ 'LONG_EMAIL'}}</div>
        <div ng-if="!forgotForm.username.$error.minlength" ng-message="pattern">{{ 'INVALID_EMAIL' }}</div>
      </div>
      <input type="text" id="username-remember" name="username" 
        ng-model="username" ng-minlength="8" ng-maxlength="200" 
        required ng-pattern="email_regexp" 
        ng-class="{ 'has-error': submittedFrgPwd && forgotForm.username.$invalid || submittedError}"/>
</form>
```

[**Update Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/N3dMwhafAsA37KGvT6z8?p=preview)

Comment: @brabertaser1992 I thinkyo forgot to update plunkr..please do it

Comment: no, all is ok in link: <div ng-message="minlength, required">You did not enter a field</div> - this didn't work

Comment: suppose our minlength is 5 & then how can required will satisfied if length is..`ng-message="minlength, required"` is technically incorrect..it means that if `minlength` is satisfied then show required..

Comment: no. logic is such: if minlength not valid - skip pattern, if valid - then pattern check

as i do: `data-ng-show="submittedFrgPwd && forgotForm.username.$error.pattern && !forgotForm.username.$error.minlength && !forgotForm.username.$error.maxlength"` - but it is to ugly

Comment: @brabertaser1992 hey but `ng-message="minlength,pattern"` this should work in any case

Answer (score -1):

if you are seeing the handlers, it probably means there was an error somewhere. My best best is that ngMessages was not injected.

```
angular.module('app',['ngTranslate', 'ngMessages'])
```

Additionally, you could make use of angularjs form default to check for submission i.e. forgotForm.$submitted.

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': forgotForm.$submitted && forgotForm.username.$invalid }">
```

You also do not need to use pattern for type=email unless there are some specific scenarios you want to test (e.g. email domain). ng-message='email' should be able to handle whether email is valid or not.

```
<div ng-message="email">{{ 'INVALID_EMAIL' | translate }}</div>
```

In any case, I have attached the plunker link below
http://run.plnkr.co/Em2eBprmn74FqSYu/

I have included bootstrap css which i found is helpful when validating (and change the html code a lil bit).

hope this helps.

Comment: mail@localhost by html5 is valid, but in my app it's not a valid pattern, sure all is injected.